# Search area on google results

Tags: search, google-search

When you search for a site like Stack Overflow on Google, the result that comes up includes its own search bar for searching that particular site. It appears below the description of the site like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL8ZB.jpg]

How do I make this search area appear inside the Google result of our sites ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! What programming language are you using? Can you please show what you have attempted so far?

Comment: My edit is waiting for review but I added a description of the image you linked to. It's better not to rely solely on an image to get across what you're trying to accomplish, especially when you haven't/can't embed the image. Not everyone will be able to see it and the question becomes broken when that link no longer works. (My edit also embeds the image into the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have much control over that:

> "The Sitelinks search box appears only for navigational queries and
>   when relevant for users. Google algorithms use a variety of factors to
>   determine when the box appears, including the information on the site
>   and different types of navigational queries from Search users."

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview